# ASP.NET MVC Validation: result in a javascript property?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Validation. I want to know in my javascript functions whether the validation has error.

Is there any builtin javascript property integrated with ASP.NET MVC Framework to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in ASP.NET MVC validation is server-side only so there is no standard variable like *Page_IsValid* from ASP.NET.

If you want to add client-side validation you could use [xVal](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xval) or [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Some articles on xVal:

- [xVal - a validation framework for ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/10/xval-a-validation-framework-for-aspnet-mvc/)
- [Client-side form validation made easy](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-3-how-to-cover-all-your-client-side-form-validation-needs-without-writing-any-javascript-part1/)

As an option you could validate data on a server and render this JavaScript code in a view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Page_IsValid = <%= ViewData.ModelState.IsValid %>;
</script>
```